# How to move a face on a curved mesh

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to move the selected face on a curved mesh without getting the mesh distorted?
I need to be able to reposition the face within the area.

[image]

Comment: use a Shrinkwrap modifier with another sphere as target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your transform orientation to normal g+x or g+y or using the transform widget will give you the transform you want for this mesh.
[image]
If it has more geometry, being truly curved, put your 3d cursor in the center and rotate the geometry with the 3D cursor set as your transform.

Using shrink-wrap or snapping to another object can give some distortion.

Comment: I was doing the grab then moving along an axis, but it goes off the mesh, I would like if its possible even with low poly mesh, the face I want to move around to be able to stick to the mesh, is there a way?

Comment: Hold shift when dragging for a slower, more precise control of transforms. You can turn on snapping with ctrl+Shift and then changing the snapping settings to face(next to the transform orientations I shared. But, this and using the shrinkwrap modifier will distort the geometry. In object mode try snapping an object to a plane and adding align rotation to target. These are all the solutions I can think of. If you are new to modeling, accuracy is not essential, but understanding orientation and snapping will make your work easier.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. How ever I'll add some more info. This is not a separate object I'm trying to move around the mesh. What I have done is chose a face, and inset it. Therefor its a face inset on the main spherical mesh which I'm trying to move around within the face quad.

Comment: My original answer to use normal transform does exactly as you describe.